# Bring the cursor to start of file?

Tags: python, file-handling

I want to save the unique words in my `myWords.txt` file. I am searching a word and if finds in the file, it does not write it, but if it does not find, it writes that word. The problem is, when I run the program second time, the pointer is at the end of file and search from the end of file and write the word again that wrote last time. I tried to use `seek(0)` at some positions but does not work. Am I doing something wrong?

```
with open("myWords.txt", "r+") as a:
#    a.seek(0)
    word = "naughty"
    for line in a:
        if word == line.replace("\n", "").rstrip():
            break
        else:
            a.write(word + "\n")
            print("writing " +word)
            a.seek(0)
            break

    a.close()
```

**myWords.txt**

```
awesome
shiny
awesome
clumsy
shiny
```

On running code two times

**myWords.txt**

```
awesome
shiny
awesome
clumsy
shiny
naughty
naughty
```

Comment: there is no sense to put anything after `break`. You have to put it before `break`

Comment: @furas Thanks. Edited. I also tried it before that but does not work..

Comment: I think you have wrong indention. You need `for/else` construnction, not `if/else` - so `else` has to be belowe `for`

Comment: @furas `else` has to be below for ? it is already.

Comment: now it is belowe `if` - it has to have the same indention as `for`

Comment: @furas It cannot work. `else` has to be after the `if`.

Comment: It will work - `for/else` is special Python construction.

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `a.close()` at the end because the `with open(...) as a:` automatically ensures that the file will always get closed.

Comment: @martineau Ohh i see.. Got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong indention - now it finds different text in first line and automatically adds `naughty` because it doesn't check other lines.

You have to use `for/else/break` construction. `else` has the same indention as `for`.

If program find `naughty` then it use `break` to leave `for` loop and `else` will be skip. If `for` doesn't find `naughty` then it doesn't use `break` and then `else` will be executed.

```
with open("myWords.txt", "r+") as a:
    word = "naughty"
    for line in a:
        if word == line.strip():
            print("found")
            break
    else: # no break 
        a.write(word + "\n")
        print("writing:", word)

    a.close()
```

It works similar to

```
with open("myWords.txt", "r+") as a:
    word = "naughty"

    found = False

    for line in a:
        if word == line.strip():
            print("found")
            found = True
            break

    if not found:
        a.write(word + "\n")
        print("writing:", word)

    a.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file in append mode, by setting "a" or "ab" as the mode. See open().

When you open with "a" mode, the write position will always be at the end of the file (an append). You can open with "a+" to allow reading, seek backwards and read (but all writes will still be at the end of the file!).

Tell me if this works:

```
with open("myWords.txt", "a+") as a:

    words = ["naughty", "hello"];
    for word in words:
        a.seek(0)
        for line in a:
            if word == line.replace("\n", "").rstrip():
                break
            else:
                a.write(word + "\n")
                print("writing " + word)
                break

    a.close()
```

Hope this helps!